# Detect multiple Simultaneous Live Streams on Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to find a way to detect multiple live **simultaneous** streams on a same youtube channels.

I want to avoid using the search from the API because of the cost (100) and used since now the "get methods" by using this url : https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/live.

But when there is multiple streams in the same time this url seems to **redirect only to one of the live**.

Does anybody have a magic trick for that ?

I'm using Python and made something like that :

```
def get_channel_live_url(p_channelID):
    LiveChannelVideo = re.compile(r'https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(.*)')

    urlpage = 'https://youtube.com/channel/'+p_channelID+'/live'
    links = browse_and_return_balise(urlpage, balise='link', rel='canonical')
    for link in links:
        isLiveChannelVideo = LiveChannelVideo.search(link['href'])
        if isLiveChannelVideo != None:
            return isLiveChannelVideo.group(1)
```

where browse_and_return_balise are something like that :

```
def browse_and_return_balise(url, balise='a', class_=None, attrs=None, rel=None):
   result = []
   page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
   result = soup.find_all(balise, class_=class_, attrs=attrs, rel=rel)
   # Collect all links
   return result
```

The issue is that when a youtube channel broadcast 2 live at the same time I only catch the first one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I know the magic trick, but, you need to provide more info = how are you trying to get this data? what programming language you're using for this requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry to have been not exaustive. So I'm using python and try to detect if a channel on youtube is live and if so what is the video_id.I will update my initial question to be more clear.